# unordered_map is not recognised when i compiled through command line, but codeblocks works fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation

`unordered_map<char,int> freq;`

commands I have given are `g++ new.cpp new.o`
 and  `g++ -o program new.cpp`

*new.cpp: In function 'std::__cxx11::string frequencySort(std::__cxx11::string)':
new.cpp:5:5: error: 'unordered_map' was not declared in this scope
     unordered_map freq;
     ^*

I have g++ version 5.1.0
it compiles in codeblocks
but not through commandline or vscode

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`? This is a C++11 type. And `#include <unordered_map>`

Comment: You need to also specify `-std=c++11` in your command line.

Comment: You are strongly recommended to upgrade your gcc version. 5.x has a ABI issue which could be very annoying.